# Importing pycraf raises DLL load failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, scipy, astropy

I am trying to use `astropy` and `pycraf` for unit conversions, but when I try and `import pycraf` I get an error that says `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`. It appears to be from `scipy`, but I can `import scipy` just fine. I am using `Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)` on Windows 10. Thank you for your time.

```
WARNING: AstropyDeprecationWarning: astropy.utils.compat.funcsigs is now deprecated - use inspect instead [astropy.utils.compat.funcsigs]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\spectrum.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pycraf.conversions as cnv
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycraf\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from . import pathprof
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycraf\pathprof\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .cyprop import *

  File "pycraf/pathprof/cyprop.pyx", line 23, in init pycraf.pathprof.cyprop
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycraf\pathprof\heightprofile.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import srtm
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycraf\pathprof\srtm.py", line 37, in <module>
    from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator, RectBivariateSpline
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.py", line 175, in <module>
    from .interpolate import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 21, in <module>
    import scipy.special as spec
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 641, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Here is my very simple file.

```
import astropy.units as u
import pycraf.conversions as cnv

power = 1 * u.W

print('{:.2f}'.format(power))
 # 1.00 W

print('{:.2f}'.format(power.to(cnv.dB_W)))
 # 0.00 dB(W)

print('{:.2f}'.format(power.to(cnv.dBm)))
```

Comment: How did you install pycraf and astropy?

Comment: I installed it though conda

Comment: Oh I just did conda install pycraf and conda install astropy and I already had conda-forge in my library list

Comment: "but I can import scipy just fine": but can you `from scipy import special` without problems? It's the special module (which will have a bunch of C/Fortran compiled special functions) that's causing issues.